# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 fails when Excel is not running. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection, jet

I have a simple C# program that should read a XLS file and return it as a `DataTable` object. It fails to get the data unless the same file is opened in MS Excel -- simultaneously, at the time time of launching the program. The program uses the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider, and the `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbDataAdapter` class instances to access the data:

```
public class ExcelImport
{
    static public DataTable GetDataTable(string excelFileName, string sqlSelect)
    {
        string tpl = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;""";
        string excelConnectionString = string.Format(tpl, excelFileName);
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();        // <---- here it fails
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSelect, connection))
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
                return table;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The call looks like this:

```
        string fname = @"d:\directory\the_file.xls";
        string sqlcmd = @"
            SELECT
                [Code],
                [Name]
            FROM [Sheet1$]";
        DataTable dt = ExcelImport.GetDataTable(fname, sqlcmd);
```

The program works fine when the MS Excel (version 2016 if it matters) is running, and the exact file is open. Otherwise, the `connection.Open();` fails with the following message:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException occurred
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Neočekávaná chyba z externího ovladače databáze (1).
  Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at ExcelImport.GetDataTable(String excelFileName, String sqlSelect) in D:\__XXXX_webapp\WEBAPP\WEBAPP\App_Code\ExcelImport.cs:line 20
   at cz.company.mylogin.DataPump.DataPumpTheFileXLS() in D:\__XXXX_webapp\DataPump\Program.cs:line 249
   at cz.company.mylogin.DataPump.Main() in D:\__XXXX_webapp\DataPump\Program.cs:line 308
```

Based on the reported HRESULT error, I have found the related reason https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/295297/prb-error-message-0x80004005-general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key

I do not know whether the explanation for the HRESULT is misleading or whether it really is the reason.

**The questions are:** Why it works when the same file is open in MS Excel? What more should be done to get the data without running the Excel?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in that link?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it had no visible effect. For the Message, it says "Message=Unexpected error from the external database driver[or controller] (1)." I admint I do a mistake somewhere. I am simply searching what is wrong, what to try, and how to fix it.

Comment: Not really a solution, but worth to mention: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/10/18/unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1-microsoft-jet-database-engine-after-applying-october-security-updates/

Comment: @pepr: did you get solution to this problem?

Comment: @dhirajsuvarna: No, I have no reliable solution. Meanwhile, I have changed the approach, and I am using CSV instead of XLS(X).

Comment: @pepr: You can use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to connect to XLSX

Comment: @dhirajsuvarna: I cannot use ACE as there is the conflict 32-bit vs. 64-bit with the installed MS Office. And I am not allowed to change it.